# How to capture the detail of an attribute in a sentence?

Tags: nlp, grammar-inference

The problem is best explained using an example, so please consider the sentence below:

Made of airy *cotton* with a touch of stretch, the Pinafore Dress features a modern *square neckline*.

Here, *cotton* (FABRIC) and *square neckline* (NECKLINE) are two important attributes in the sentence. What I need to do is to capture the word *airy* which is a detail of the fabric. FABRIC and NECKLINE can be successfully captured using NER, but NER is not working well when it comes to capturing the detail terms like *airy*.

Can someone point out how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using dependency parsing for that, e.g., as implemented in [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features) or any other NLP toolkit.

The details should be adjective modifiers (dependency label *amod*) of what you call attribute that you detected using a NER-like approach.

[image]

Alternatively, they can form compound nouns as "airy cotton" in your example. In this case, it is a word that depends on the entity with the dependency label *compound*. But I guess this will be rarely the case because such compounds will be more often recognized as one entity.

[image]

Spacy has an [online demo for dependency parsing](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy?text=Made%20of%20airy%20cotton%20with%20a%20touch%20of%20stretch%2C%20the%20Pinafore%20Dress%20features%20a%20modern%20square%20neckline.&model=en_core_web_sm&cpu=1&cph=0).